# Could I use \cutout to put text at the center of paragraph?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig, shapepar, cutwin

Actually, I need to use `\shapepar` with `\cutout` or `\begin{ctuout}` but I have two problems
1.Could I use `\cutout` to put text at the center of paragraph?
2.And to add `\includegraphics`

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx,cutwin}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\begin{document}
\opencutcenter
\cutout{}(15em,-6\baselineskip)\shapepar {\circleshape}
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut\par
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a modification of your MWE.

```
% cutoutprob.tex  SE 561036

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\let\cutout\relax % don't want shapepar's \cutout, need cutwin's version
\usepackage{graphicx,cutwin}

\begin{document}

% put this in the cutout
\renewcommand{\windowpagestuff}{\centering 
\shapepar {\circleshape}
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut\par
}

\opencutcenter % rectangular cutout in center of text
\begin{cutout}{3}{0.3\textwidth}{0.3\textwidth}{10}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{cutout}
\end{document}
```

[image]
It creates a rectangular cutout in the `text` paragraph and then inserts the `cut` text shape into the center of the cutout.

If you want to put a graphic into the cutout then modify `\windowpagestuff` accordingly to something like

```
renewcommand{\windowpagestuff}{\centering \includegraphics{...}}.
```